# Run parametrized test from console

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testcase, nunit-3.0, nunit-console

I'd like to run test method with only one set of params from a testcase.

I'm using NUnit Console 3.4.1.

Example of code:

```
[Category("SmokeTests")]
[TestCase("1 param", "2 param", "3 param")]
[TestCase("aaa", "bbb", "ccc")]
public void TestMethod(string a, string b, string c)
{
    // do something
}
```

Command-line to be run:

```
nunit3-console.exe UiTests.dll --where "cat==SmokeTests and name==TestMethod(\"aaa\", \"bbb\", \"ccc\")" --result C:\temp\result.xml
```

Currently NUnit returns an error

> Unexpected token '(' at position 50 in selection expression.

Comment: I don't have possibility to check that in usage, but try to escape ( as well, so add \ before ( and )... To have something like this:name==TestMethod\\(\"aaa\", \"bbb\", \"ccc\"\\)

Comment: Actually I've checked both cases, error is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were very close to the answer.

Your query was

```
--where "cat==SmokeTests and name==TestMethod(\"aaa\", \"bbb\", \"ccc\")"
```

There are three things wrong with the query:

1. You were right to think that the quotes need to be escaped with backslashes (`\"`), but due to the way the arguments are interpreted, the backslashes themselves need to be escaped too (`\\\"`).
2. To get around the

   > Unexpected token '(' at position 50 in selection expression.

   you have to also wrap the `name` parameter in quotes (these quotes only need to be escaped *once*).
3. When NUnit constructs its name for a method, it comma-separates the arguments, but **without spaces**. The name of the test you're trying to run in your example is

   ```
   TestMethod("aaa","bbb","ccc")
   ```

   not

   ```
   TestMethod("aaa", "bbb", "ccc")
   ```

---

The query that should work, then, is:

```
--where "cat==SmokeTests and name==\"TestMethod(\\\"aaa\\\",\\\"bbb\\\",\\\"ccc\\\")\""
```

The arguments passed into `nunit3-console.exe` are then:

- `--where`
- `cat==SmokeTests and name=="TestMethod(\"aaa\",\"bbb\",\"ccc\")"`

then NUnit can parse the `name` arugment, handling the escaped quotes, and running the test you desire.

Reference: [Test Selection Language](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/running-tests/Test-Selection-Language.html) in the [NUnit documentation](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/intro.html).

Comment: I realise this question is nearly four years old, but I just tried to do the same thing and really struggled.